# How to POST from WebForms to External URL and Supply Values from Server

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Having lived in an MVC world for the last few years I just cannot get my head back into a WebForms world.

I have to try to integrate an external payment getway into a 4 step process. The last step involves POSTing some values to a given URL. This URL is expecting a preset list of values with predefined names (i.e. I cannot change what it is expecting).

The problem I am having is populating values gained from steps 1-3 on the form I want to post.

Let's say I need to send 3 values (there are more but the principle is the same):

```
- amount
- returnurl
- name
```

I could write a form along the lines of

```
<form action="http://url/goes/here">
    <p>Please confirm the details below</p>
    <asp:TextBox id="amount" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox id="returnurl" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox id="name" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button id="submitme" />
</form>
```

And easily pre-populate the textboxes (or labels, or whatever I need) from the codebehind on `PageLoad`.

But then the values are submitted with prefixed with the 'ctl00$ContentBottom$WebFormControl$ctl00$' and so the external url throws it away and complains no values have been supplied. It sees 'ctl00$ContentBottom$WebFormControl$ctl00$amount' and not 'amount'.

Is there anyway I can amend the names of the values that are posted?

Answer (score 0):

instead of amending the names of value you can add them in your aspx page as follows

```
        <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_name" value="<%=txtbox1.Text%>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_address" value="<%=txtbox2.Text%>" > 
        <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_email" value="<%=txtbox3.Text%>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="billing_cust_notes" value="<%=txtbox4.Text%>">
```

When the form is ready to be posted change the value and then post.